# How to check whether a file downloaded from a ftp location is completed or not using apache camel

Tags: ftp, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I need to check whether the file downloaded from a ftp location using camel is completed, being downloaded or the connection broke. If completed I need to do a certain function else I need to make another call

Comment: One solution is to add a tempPrefix to the fileName being downloaded. So for example if the filename being downloaded is abc.txt, while downloading the file would appear as abc.txt.yourtempprefix and then after completion it will be abc.txt. This way you can identify whether the file is completely downloaded or not. http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Comment: How to add prefix to the filename while it is being downloaded

Comment: show your route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FTP` component also has the capabilities of `File2`. If you check the [docs](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) you'll see options for `preMove`, `move`, and `moveFailed`. You can change the names of files and/or change the location of files before processing, after successful processing, and after failure.